# find all subgroups between subgroups

Tags: python, algorithm

i have a list of subgroups: `((1,2),(3,4),(5,6,7))`

i need to get all subgroups between the given subgroups (and not just subgroup inside subgroups),

so for the example above i will get:

```
((1,3),(1,4),(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,3,7),(1,4,5).....)
```

i have tried :

```
itertools.product(*[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]])
```

but the result is:

(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
(1, 3, 7)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 6)
(1, 4, 7)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
(2, 3, 7)
(2, 4, 5)
(2, 4, 6)
(2, 4, 7)

but (1,3) is also a valid group (and it missing from the result)

Comment: Is [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) what you are looking for?

Comment: its almost what i need, i updated the question

Comment: Do you only go one way? I mean are (1,5),(1,6) and (3,5),(4,6) valid subgroups?

Comment: @EyalCh If I understand you correctly then this can be emulated by adding a dummy value to each tuple representing "no value" (it can be `None` if it doesn't appear as value), then doing itertools.product and then filtering out those dummy values. However there are some weird edge cases. What if the input is `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3]]`? Then the result `[1, 2]` is ambiguous. And it will always be unless you assume that those inner tuples don't share elements. Also, is empty list `[]` an expected value? Rules for creating the output are a bit unclear.

Comment: thanks @freakish adding 'dummy' value will do the job